# About $\sum_{i\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n+i)_{n+1}}$ and $\sum_{i\geq 1}\frac{1}{i^2-i-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I was playing around with Zeta function and changed it as following to find that

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i\cdot(i+1)\cdot(i+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(i+n)} = \frac{1}{n\cdot n!}$$
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2-i-1} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt5} \cdot \tan\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt5}{2}\right)$$

Any ideas on how to prove these identities?

PS: I reversed engineered these values from WolframAlpha so looking for analytical solution  or references there of.

Comment: They are not that similar. The first series is a telescopic series while the second one can be computed through the reflection formula for the $\psi=\frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma$ function.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean similar in that manner but removed that word now. Can you point out the references where I can read more. Simpler explanation over here will be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{i(i+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(i+n)} = \frac{1}{n}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{i(i+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(i+n-1)}-\frac{1}{(i+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(i+n)}\right)$$
hence the first series is a telescopic series. About the second one:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b} $$
[and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula)
$$ \psi(z)-\psi(1-z) = -\pi\cot(\pi z) $$
rapidly prove your claim.

Comment: Thanks I will try to read more about telescopic series and ψ